# Bash: reduce long consequtive repeating patterns from huge file, including multi-line

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have big text files (Reddit dumps), and a module of my text mining program crashes when meets long repeating patterns (see below). I understand that this problem is complex and might be better to address it with multiple commands. I want to reduce these repetitions, i.e. leave only one example: "AA AA AA" -> "AA".

Here are strings which cause problems (please excuse me for politics and obscenity, that's example of real data - I've cleaned the worst):

```
$ grep -oP "\b(.{25,}?)\1+\b" RS_2017-05.all_ascii_cleaned.txt


HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST 
Bridge Officer Training |       Bridge Officer Training |
        |       Bridge Officer Training |       Bridge Officer Training
BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS 
sumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonje
TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS TYT SUCKS 
Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=Y=
HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST HILLARY LOST 
, Martial Skill of Choice, Martial Skill of Choice
BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS BUZZFEED SUCKS 
 him to your house, you brought him to your house, you brought
IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS IMMATURE CUCKS 
 him to your house, you brought him to your house, you brought
I clear ball, teammate takes ball and loses possession immediately, opponent shoots. I clear ball, teammate takes ball and loses possession immediately, opponent shoots. 
 http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id        
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
```

Patterns can consist of any symbols. The worst thing are multi-line patterns like:

```
r
r
r
r
```

or

```
01
00
01
00
01
```

What I tried:

The regex I accomplished to write for the repetitions within a line,works in grep, but does not help much in sed and hangs somewhy: `sed -E "s/(.{4,}?)\1+/\1/g" test.txt`.

Long single-character pattern "GGGGG..." can be addressed with this: `sed 's/\(.\)\1\+/\1/g' test.txt`, but I can't set minimum repetition limit there.

Single repeating line can be reduced by this code I found: `sed '$!N; /^\(.*\)\n\1$/!P; D' test.txt`, but I can't set minimal limit there.

The problem is also the last case. Of course, keeping in memory too long multi-line window might be very slow, but can I at least have a parameter letting me to reduce repeating patterns, say, up to three or four lines?

---

EDIT: Example what I want to achieve:

Example input:

```
RegExr v3 was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple.

HAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHAHA
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG

Edit the Expression & TextTextTextTextText to TATATATATA see $$$$$$$$$ matches. X X X X X X X X Roll over matches or the expression lolk lolk lolk lolk
lolk
r
r
r
r
r
RADA
RADA
RADA
RADA

JOHN01
BAD
JOHN01
BAD
JOHN01
BAD
JOHN01
BAD

r

Here is some more good text.

ONE TWO ONE TWO ONE TWO ONE TWO ONE TWO ONE TWO ONE TWO ONE TWO ONE TWO

sumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonjesumyeonje


This is also a good text, but repeated. This is also a good text, but repeated. This is also a good text, but repeated. 

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

Here is how I want to get corpus cleaned (ideal case):

```
RegExr v3 was created by gskinner.com, and is proudly hosted by Media Temple.

HA
G

Edit the Expression & Text to TA see $ matches. X Roll over matches or the expression lolk 
lolk
r

RADA


JOHN01
BAD


r

Here is some more good text.

ONE TWO 
sumyeonje


This is also a good text, but repeated.

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
```

---

EDIT2: As long, as I just want to eliminate the situation when my program crashes, I think the minimal repeated element is enough to check with:

```
HAHAHA_2_HAHAHA_2_HAHAHA_2 -> HA_2_HA_2_HA_2
```

If there will be problems after that, I will remember this possible cause and just run this cleaning second time.

If I will run the cleaning of repeated lines after initial cleaning of words, then everything should be Ok:

```
HAHAHAHAHA            HA         HA
RADARADA              RADA       RADA
HAHAHAHAHA     --->   HA    --->
RADARADA              RADA
```

Comment: Is the order and line number of each word important? If not, then there is a very simple solution.

Comment: @Socowi I am doinng POS tagging, so yes. "I clear ball" -> "PRP, JJ, NN".

Comment: The man page itself tells you that `-P` is "highly experimental" and you can google for other examples of grep crashing when it's used and that option has since been removed from some grep versions so you're getting pretty much the expected outcome! If you post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output then I'm sure someone can help you solve your problem in a way that isn't "highly experimental". wrt `I can't set minimum repetition limit there` - sure you can: `sed -E '/X{3,5}/'` will find 3 to 5 X's.

Comment: My last comment to hopefully drive home what I at least perceive as a lack of clarity in your requirements: in your posted example - why does `TATA...` become `TA` but  `gskinner.com` doesn't become `gskiner.com` (repeated `n`)? Why doesn't `good` become `god` (repeated `o`)? Why doesn't `This is also` become `This also` (repeated `is`)? Why does `lolk\nlolk` exist in the output?

Answer (score 1):

You may need multiple strategies, for repeated lines `uniq` will work
For 2-line repeats you can merge the lines and run `uniq` on the result.  For example

```
$ cat repeat_line2

01
00
01
00
01
00
01
00

$ awk '{ORS=NR%2?FS:RS}1' repeat_line2 | uniq
01 00
```

For repeated words on the same line, you can apply the inverse operation.  Split the lines and before you run `uniq`

```
$ cat repeat_words
AA AA AA AA
CC BB CC BB


$ sed 1G repeat_words    |  # double space lines
  tr ' ' '\n'            |  # break words into new lines
  uniq                   |  # remove repeated words
  awk '{ORS=NR%2?FS:RS}1'|  # join two lines
  uniq                      # remove repeated two-words
```

will give

```
AA
CC BB
```

you can implement all these in a single `awk` script, but I think piping to specialized commands will make it easier to debug/improve.

Comment: Interesting. I had thought of various possible interpretations of what the OP was trying to do but none of them were the above. Not saying you're wrong, I really have no idea. In particular I thought that `01 00 01...` multi-line string was a single string that the OP wanted to find repetitions of.

Comment: @EdMorton Np, the biggest problem is multi-line repeats indeed.

Comment: Thanks very much for your solution! As far, as I see, one of the things you suggest to remove line breaks and switch to a single-line case. I was also thinking about the solution, but I wonder how much it affects quality of the output - whether it matters for the program I use or not. So I wanted to preserve line breaks, if possible.

Comment: Also I want to preserve actual text meaning (I am mining meaningful keyphrases from text, using POS tagging and other things), so `uniq` over the text seems too radical, it will transform to "bag of words".

Comment: My actual data is reddit dumps, which is like "<some good text><some other good text><BAD SEQUENCE LIKE IN MY EXAMPLE><another good text>"

Comment: @Slowpoke it's extremely important for you to edit your question to do what I suggested in my first comment, i.e. post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output, because right now your question is extremely vague. I can't even tell if you're trying to match on repetitions of a specific string, or find repetitions of any strings that match a specific regexp or something else entirely.

Comment: @EdMorton I've updated the question with the example of the result I want to achieve. Please excuse me for not being clear.

Comment: You're getting there. You've now shown us an example of what you want to get out but you haven't explained why that should be the output. How is a tool supposed to determine that "RADA" is a repeated string and "JOHN01\nBAD" is a repeated string and "RADA\n\nJOHN01" isn't a unique string and so on. What if there were no newlines between the last RADA and the first JOHN01? Again, edit your question to explain your rules for selecting which strings are/arn't identified as repeating.

Comment: @EdMorton Your example is a bit unclear to me. I am searching only for a consecutive repeatings of the same thing. Let it be the minimal element which repeats after itself. If there was space instead of the line break, we had "RADA RADA JOHN01", where RADA is being repeated, and JOHN01 starts new possible sequence. 

It's like in the line "HAHAHAHA" the least repeating element is "HA", so reducing it like these fully satisfies me.

Comment: @EdMorton You possibly mean that repeating pattern can include much more than two strings, let it be three: "John01\n bad\n good\n John01\n bad\n good". I understand that this is computationally expensive to check so many strings, so I thought about the possibility to limit searching for such a pattern with 3-5 strings, something like `/.../{2,5}`
I am not searching for very high theoretical precision, only to eliminate long sequences which make my program crash.

Comment: @EdMorton I have updated my question with the explanation I believe answers your question.

Comment: So `HAHA` is 2 repetitions of `HA`. Is `HAHA HAHA` 2 repetitions of `HAHA` or 4 repetitions of `HA`? How do you know? Is `BOOKBOOK` 2 repetitions of `BOOK` or is it a `B` then 2 repetitions of `O` then `KB` then 2 more repetitions of `O` then a `K`? I'm still not seeing in your question how to identify which [sub]strings can be idenfitied as "repeating"

Comment: How about `HAHATAT` is that 1 `HAH` then 2 `AT`s or 2 `HA`s then one `TAT` or something else? Hopefully you understand my confusion and can provide the rules in your question on how to identify which strings to identify as repeating. To be honest right now your question sounds completely impossible to write a program to solve in any practical amount of time.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a start (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;s/((\b|[[:punct:]]).+)\s*\1/\1/;ta' file | uniq
```

This removes duplicate lines and cuts duplicate words to a minimum.

Comment: potong your sed one-liner is pure gold but i'm struggling to understand. mind if I ask you for a detailed explanation? (just the sed part)

Comment: @Forge the substitution command is placed in a loop which will repeat until unsuccessful. The LHS of the substitution tries to match a group of word(s) followed by a space followed by a  repetition of the previous group. It is greedy, so matches the longest string. It keeps going until no repeats are found then the `uniq` command removes any successive lines that repeat.